# Secrets & Keys - Event Hub

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-keyvault

I have a third party external Event Hub Producer client sending events to my Event Hub Queue.

I plan to use Key Vault to provide the third party with Client ID/Secret and Event Hub String.

Will this still require me to distribute User Credentials to the third party in order to access the Vault Secrets/Keys for the Event Hub?

Comment: I would suggest using shared access key. You gave have full control over the lifetime, permissions and scope. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/authenticate-shared-access-signature.

Answer (score 0):

If you used Azure key vault for storing the EventHub connection string and service principal with Access policies in place, then your third party needs to use the service principal credentials if you want to obtain the secret - the answer is YES!

```
static KeyVaultClient GetClient() => new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(async (string authority, string resource, string scope) =>
{
    var context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, TokenCache.DefaultShared);
    ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
    var authResult = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);
    return authResult.AccessToken;
}));
```

The full sample you can find here [here](https://appswin.co.th/2018/02/26/c-retrieve-key-secret-certificate-from-azure-keyvault/).

Also, you can use Azure AD to enable [access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory) to the EventHub.

Comment: Thank you, this is still secure though based on secret is matched to a value in KV? I'd prefer to put secrets in Vault as i can apply IP Whitelists for a bit more defence in depth.

Comment: The secret is in the Vault, and with the sample above you are using the service principal to obtain it. Adding more security when required is always a good idea I believe...